# TomEE OpenEJBException caused by ClassNotFoundException for class of name 'empty string'

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, servlets, apache-tomee

When attempting to launch TomEE with Java Server Faces web app running Mojarra 2.2.0, I get a ClassNotFoundException caused by a Servlet with a class name of ""(empty string).  I've trapped the error with the debugger in hopes of figuring out where the empty string is coming from.  Don't all of the servlet class names get specified in the web.xml file?  Has anyone run into this? Is the web.xml file corrupted somehow?

The exception stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/CopSync]
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to load servlet class: : <-- Class name goes here
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:2061)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:1824)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:355)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory$Chain.deploy(ConfigurationFactory.java:396)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:938)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1179)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1054)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    at org.apache.openejb.core.TempClassLoader.loadClass(TempClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.TempClassLoader.loadClass(TempClassLoader.java:74)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:2054)
    ... 17 more
```

Edit: added screen shot of debugger variables values.
Screen shot of variables state from Eclipse debugger:
[image]

Code snippet from AnnotationDeployer where the OpenEJBException is being thrown:

```
          if (servletClass != null && servlet.getJspFile() == null) { // jaxrs application doesn't have a jsp file
                if (!"org.apache.openejb.server.rest.OpenEJBRestServlet".equals(servletClass)) {
                    try {
                        Class clazz = classLoader.loadClass(servletClass);
                        classes.add(clazz);
                        if (servlet.getServletClass() == null) {
                            servlet.setServletClass(servletClass);
                        }
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        if (servlet.getServletClass() != null) {
 line 2061                           throw new OpenEJBException("Unable to load servlet class: " + servletClass, e);
                        } else {
                            logger.error("servlet " + servlet.getServletName() + " has no servlet-class defined and is not a subclass of Application");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Code snippet from TempClassLoader

```
       final String resourceName = name.replace('.', '/') + ".class";

        //Copy the input stream into a byte array
        final byte[] bytes;
        this.bout.reset();
        InputStream in = null;

        try {

            in = this.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);

            if (in != null && !(in instanceof BufferedInputStream)) {
                in = new BufferedInputStream(in);
            }

            if (in == null) {
line 141                throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
            }

            IO.copy(in, this.bout);
            bytes = this.bout.toByteArray();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException(name, e);
        } finally {
            IO.close(in);
        }
```

The web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ProjectName</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class></servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jaxrs/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ProjectName</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProjectName</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1101-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an empty `servlet class` when defining the `JAX-RS Servlet`

```
<servlet>
    <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class></servlet-class>   <!-- HERE -->
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

In this situation the servlet container tries to load the class with an empty name, which is generally wrong and thus an `Exception` is thrown.

You have to provide the fully-qualified class name for the Servlet, for example:

```
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
```